# iterar lista, buscar elemento y que devuelva la ultima posición de ese elemento en la lista

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy inciando en Python, en mi curso nos enviaron este ejercicio donde nos piden que la funcion busque en una lista, el elemento e y en este caso devuelva LA ULTIMA posicion del elemento en la lista. Pienso que en el if deberia ir un AND que denote esta condicion pero no estoy segura como! hice algunos intentos pero ningun fructifero. Alguien me da una mano? Gracias!

```
def buscar_u_elemento(lista,e):
    pos = -1
    for i, z in enumerate (lista):
        if z == e :
            pos = i
            break
    return(pos)
print(buscar_u_elemento([1,2,3,2,3,4,5,6], 2))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma mas simple es recorrer tu lista a la inversa con un for y un rango invertido al encontrarte tu primer valor lo retornas, te recomiendo hacer algo como esto:

El metodo `range(start,end,iterate)` acepta 3 parametros 1 el inicio, 2 el fin y 3 el incremento en cada loop, sí utilizas el incremento en -1 vas a restarle por lo que te permitirá recorrer de forma inversa sin problemas.

```
def buscar_u_elemento(lista,e):
    for i in range(len(lista)-1,0,-1):
        if lista[i]==e :
            return i

print(buscar_u_elemento([1,2,3,2,3,4,5,6], 2))
```

Espero te sea útil.

Comment: Muchas gracias! muy claro

Answer (score 0):

Lo mas eficiente sería recorrer desde el fondo, ya que si lo haces desde el principio, te vas a tener que recorrer todo el arreglo. Si es desde el fondo, tan pronto lo encuentres, sales:

```
def buscar(lista, item):
    i = len(lista) - 1
    while i >= 0:
        if lista[i] == item:
            return i
        i-=1
    # si llegamos aqui, no esta
    return -1
```

Comment: Hola! lo probe pero independientemente del item, siempre me esta devolciendo -1, como si el ciclo while no funcionara

Comment: Lo acabo de probar en mi equipo pasando `[1,2,3,2,3,4,5,6], 2` como parámetros y me da 3, tanto python 2 como 3.

Answer (score 0):

El método `rfind` retorna la última ocurrencia de dentro de un string, por lo cual primero convertimos la lista de enteros en una lista de string usando

```
map(str, lista)
```

La lista la convertimos en un string usando `join` y luego buscamos el valor deseado:

```
def buscar(lista, valor):
    return "".join(map(str, lista)).rfind(str(valor))

valores = [1,2,3,2,3,4,5,6]
print(buscar(valores, 2))
```